# Is there a SQL update query to update the same value for multiple records within the same user id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-statement, sql-update

I have a column that is used for calculations only. It displays either a 0 or a positive number which represents vacation time. In our Time table it is entered as a negative number and I convert it to a positive number for calculations. I need that positive value to go into the NonWorkHrs column for each entry by an employee. It needs to be the same value for all records within a user ID.

I have tried using case statements and select max within a sub-query

```
update DME
set NonWorkHrs = 
(
 select max(VacationHours)
 from DME b
 where useruid = b.useruid
 and useruid in (1,2,3)
 and NonWorkHrsHolder > 0
)
where useruid in (1,2,3)
```

I also tried a case statement

```
update DME
set NonWorkHrs =
(case 
  when (VacationHours > 0)
  then (VacationHours)
 --no else statement is need. All rows should have the same value
 end
 ) 
where useruid in (1,2,3)
```

I convert the negative TimeEntered values to positive values in the VacationHours column. The NonWorkHrs column is used to in calculations to determine the actual work hours.

The expected result is

```
Useruid UserFullName    NonWorkHrs  VacationHours   TimeEntered
1       Jane Doe         8             8             -8
1       Jane Doe         8             0              10
1       Jane Doe         8             0              12
2       John Doe         18            18            -18
2       John Doe         18            0              23
3       Bob Builder      16            16            -16
3       Bob Builder      16            0              40
```

The actual result is

```
Useruid UserFullName    NonWorkHrs  VacationHours   TimeEntered
1       Jane Doe          18           8             -8
1       Jane Doe          18           0              10
1       Jane Doe          18           0              12
2       John Doe          18           18            -18
2       John Doe          18           0              23
3       Bob Builder       18           16            -16
3       Bob Builder       18           0              40
```

Comment: Remove `and useruid in (1,2,3)` from the inner query and see what that gives you.

Comment: What does the database look like prior to your updates?

Comment: the problem is that there is no unique key to distinguish the records. you need to create a unique key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression):

```
  ;WITH vacationsPerUser as (
      SELECT userId, max(VacationHours) as maxVacationHours
      FROM DME 
      WHERE useruid in (1,2,3)
        and NonWorkHrsHolder > 0
      GROUP BY userId
     )
  Update b
    SET b.NonWorkHrs = ISNULL(vacationsPerUser.maxVacationHours, 0)
    FROM DME b 
    LEFT JOIN vacationsPerUser
         ON vacationsPerUser.UserId = b.UserId
    WHERE b.useruid in (1,2,3);
```

Comment: The CTE worked beautifully Renat. Thank you so much. I guess I need to spend more time understanding CTEs :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add I am able to use this CTE to update other columns in a similar fashion. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This query should work, try it.

```
DECLARE @DME TABLE
(
Useruid int,
UserFullName varchar(200),
NonWorkHrs  int,
VacationHours   int,
TimeEntered int
)

INSERT INTO @DME
VALUES
(1,'Jane Doe',18,8,-8),
(1,'Jane Doe',18,0,10),
(1,'Jane Doe',18,0,12),
(2,'John Doe',18,18,-18),
(2,'John Doe',18,0,23),
(3,'Bob Builder',18,16,-16),
(3,'Bob Builder',18,0,40)

SELECT d.* FROM @DME d

    UPDATE @DME
        SET NonWorkHrs = T2.VacationHours
    FROM @DME T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(VacationHours) AS VacationHours, Useruid FROM @DME GROUP BY Useruid) AS T2 
    ON T2.Useruid = T1.Useruid


SELECT d.* FROM @DME d
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this (gives same as your expected result)

```
UPDATE a
    SET NonWorkHrs = ABS(sub.minNegativeTime)
FROM DME a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT useruid, MIN(TimeEntered) minNegativeTime
    FROM DME b
    WHERE b.TimeEntered < 0
    GROUP BY Useruid
) sub ON sub.Useruid = a.Useruid
```